# When using CREATE USER in a stored procedure, how to specify the database for the user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a boatload of users for different databases.

It's not possible to put a `USE` statement in a stored procedure, so when I write

```
CREATE USER Foo FOR LOGIN Bar
```

How do I specify the database where the user will be created? I don't want the user to end up in the database where the stored procedure is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work for you

```
Declare @SQ Declare @SQL nvarchar(100)
Set @SQL = 'Use [DatabaseName]  
CREATE USER Foo FOR LOGIN Bar'

Exec (@SQL)
```